# Unnesting a list of lists in a data frame column

Tags: r, tidyr

To unnest a data frame I can use:

```
df <- data_frame(
    x = 1,
    y = list(a = 1, b = 2)
)

tidyr::unnest(df)
```

But how can I unnest a list inside of a list inside of a data frame column?

```
df <- data_frame(
    x = 1,
    y = list(list(a = 1, b = 2))
)
tidyr::unnest(df)
```

Error:

> Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [y]

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: Identical to the first code chunk. `data_frame(x = c(1, 1), y = c(1, 2))`

Comment: If you're trying to go wide, `df %>% mutate(y = list(as.data.frame(y))) %>% unnest()` For long, maybe `df %>% do(data_frame(x = .$x, y = unlist(.$y)))` or `df %>% mutate(y = data_frame(unlist(y))) %>% unnest()`

Comment: what's wrong with `unnest(unnest(df))`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Note**: Ignore the original and Update 1; Update 2 is better with the current state of the tidyverse.

---

**Original:**

With `purrr`, which is nice for lists,

```
library(purrr)

df %>% dmap(unlist)
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##       x     y
##   <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     1
## 2     1     2
```

which is more or less equivalent to

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))
##   x y
## a 1 1
## b 1 2
```

---

**Update 1:**

`dmap` has been deprecated and moved to [purrrlyr](https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr/), the home of interesting but ill-fated functions that will now shout lots of deprecation warnings at you. You could translate the base R idiom to tidyverse:

```
df %>% map(unlist) %>% as_tibble()
```

which will work fine for this case, but not for more than one row (a problem all these approaches face). A more robust solution might be

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% bind_rows(df) %>%    # make larger sample data
    mutate_if(is.list, simplify_all) %>%    # flatten each list element internally 
    unnest()    # expand
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     1     1
#> 4     1     2
```

---

**Update 2:**

At some point since this was asked, `tidyr::unnest()` got updated such that it doesn't error anymore, so you can just do

```r
df %>%
    unnest(y) %>% 
    unnest(y)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     2
```

If you care about the names in the list, pull them out first and then unnest the names and the list at the same time:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(label = map(y, names)) %>%
    unnest(c(y, label)) %>% 
    unnest(y)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>       x     y label
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     1 a    
#> 2     1     2 b
```

I'll leave the previous answers for continuity, but this is simpler.

Comment: dmap doesn't appear to be in purrr

Comment: ``as_data_frame() was deprecated in tibble 2.0.0.``. Also, I'd suggest placing the ``Update`` at the top of the post, since most new searches will come from users with recent package releases and will hit the ``dmap`` error.

Comment: There have been changes again, which I have adressed in my answer. Since this question still pops up, but the answers will not work anymore, I suggest updating the answer again.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in a simple step using `unnest_longer()` since *tidyr 1.0.0* :

```r
df <- tibble::tibble(
  x = 1,
  y = list(list(a = 1, b = 2))
)

library(tidyr)
unnest_longer(df,y,indices_include = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

All answers are kind of deprecated now; for the given task, I see two solutions:

```
tidyr::unnest(df, y) %>% tidyr::unnest(y)
```

does what you want, as does

```
dplyr::mutate(df, y = purrr::map(y, unlist)) |> tidyr::unnest(y)
```

although it is longer. I do not really see a good case to unnesting more than one list column in one operation, because the handling of differently sized lists inside the same row would lead to problems.