# How to unnest a list containing data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I'm trying to expand a nested column that contains a list of data frames.  They are either `NULL` or 1 row by n columns, so the goal is to just add n columns to the tibble.  (NULL list items would preferably expand to `NA`s).

I've tried several solutions including those from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860890/1086777).

The goal for the output would be a flat tibble with the following columns:
full_address, address, location.x, location.y, score, attributes.StreetName, attributes.Match_addr.

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

df <- structure(list(full_address = c("2379 ADDISON BLVD, HIGH POINT, NC 27262", 
                                "1751 W LEXINGTON AVE, HIGH POINT, NC 27262", "2514 WILLARD DAIRY RD, HIGH POINT, NC 27265", 
                                "126 MARYWOOD DR, HIGH POINT, NC 27265", "508 EDNEY RIDGE RD, GREENSBORO, NC 27408"
), json = list(NULL, NULL, structure(list(address = "2514 WILLARD DAIRY", 
                                          location = structure(list(x = -79.9766181813648, y = 36.0477204695356), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                                          score = 92.8, attributes = structure(list(StreetName = "WILLARD DAIRY", 
                                                                                    Match_addr = "2514 WILLARD DAIRY"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
               structure(list(address = "126 MARYWOOD, HIGH POINT", location = structure(list(
                 x = -80.0202617159213, y = 36.0077059145502), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                 score = 97.24, attributes = structure(list(StreetName = "MARYWOOD", 
                                                            Match_addr = "126 MARYWOOD, HIGH POINT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
               structure(list(address = "508 EDNEY RIDGE RD", location = structure(list(
                 x = -79.840872836677, y = 36.1105523384593), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                 score = 100L, attributes = structure(list(StreetName = "EDNEY RIDGE", 
                                                           Match_addr = "508 EDNEY RIDGE RD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   full_address                                json                
#>   <chr>                                       <list>              
#> 1 2379 ADDISON BLVD, HIGH POINT, NC 27262     <NULL>              
#> 2 1751 W LEXINGTON AVE, HIGH POINT, NC 27262  <NULL>              
#> 3 2514 WILLARD DAIRY RD, HIGH POINT, NC 27265 <data.frame [1 × 4]>
#> 4 126 MARYWOOD DR, HIGH POINT, NC 27265       <data.frame [1 × 4]>
#> 5 508 EDNEY RIDGE RD, GREENSBORO, NC 27408    <data.frame [1 × 4]>


df %>% unnest(json)
#> Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames


df %>% map(unlist) %>% as_data_frame()
#> Warning: `as_data_frame()` is deprecated, use `as_tibble()` (but mind the new semantics).
#> This warning is displayed once per session.
#> Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
#> * Length 5: Column `full_address`
#> * Length 18: Column `json`

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.list, simplify_all) %>%    # flatten each list element internally 
  unnest() 
#> Error: Argument 2 can't be a list containing data frames
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: YOu have some NULL elements in the list.  How do you want the expected output to be

Comment: NA.  Thanks I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(json = map(json, ~ if(is.null(.x)) data.frame(StreetName = NA_character_, Match_addr =  NA_character_) else .x))`, but the expected output is not clear to me

Comment: Do you want to `cbind` the nested dataframe into the main dataframe, so you'd get 1 normal, unnested dataframe with `colnames = c(full_address, address, location.x ...`?

Comment: Yes, @divibisan is correct.  I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the issue is that there are nested data.frame within each column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(json = map(json, ~ if(is.null(.x)) 
    tibble(attributes.StreetName = NA_character_, attributes.Match_addr =  NA_character_) 
    else do.call(data.frame, c(.x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))) %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#  full_address                     attributes.StreetNa… attributes.Match_ad… address           location.x location.y score
#  <chr>                            <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2379 ADDISON BLVD, HIGH POINT, … <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>                    NA         NA    NA  
#2 1751 W LEXINGTON AVE, HIGH POIN… <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>                    NA         NA    NA  
#3 2514 WILLARD DAIRY RD, HIGH POI… WILLARD DAIRY        2514 WILLARD DAIRY   2514 WILLARD DAI…      -80.0       36.0  92.8
#4 126 MARYWOOD DR, HIGH POINT, NC… MARYWOOD             126 MARYWOOD, HIGH … 126 MARYWOOD, HI…      -80.0       36.0  97.2
#5 508 EDNEY RIDGE RD, GREENSBORO,… EDNEY RIDGE          508 EDNEY RIDGE RD   508 EDNEY RIDGE …      -79.8       36.1 100
```

---

Or using `map_if`

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
  dat %>% 
        flatten

   }

f2 <- function(dat) {
      tibble(attributes.StreetName = NA_character_, 
             attributes.Match_addr =  NA_character_)
     }

df %>%
    mutate(json = map_if(json, is.data.frame, f1, .else = f2)) %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#  full_address                     attributes.StreetNa… attributes.Match_ad… address           score location.x location.y
#  <chr>                            <chr>                <chr>                <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 2379 ADDISON BLVD, HIGH POINT, … <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>               NA         NA         NA  
#2 1751 W LEXINGTON AVE, HIGH POIN… <NA>                 <NA>                 <NA>               NA         NA         NA  
#3 2514 WILLARD DAIRY RD, HIGH POI… WILLARD DAIRY        2514 WILLARD DAIRY   2514 WILLARD DAI…  92.8      -80.0       36.0
#4 126 MARYWOOD DR, HIGH POINT, NC… MARYWOOD             126 MARYWOOD, HIGH … 126 MARYWOOD, HI…  97.2      -80.0       36.0
#5 508 EDNEY RIDGE RD, GREENSBORO,… EDNEY RIDGE          508 EDNEY RIDGE RD   508 EDNEY RIDGE … 100        -79.8       36.1
```

Comment: @jzadra  as divisiban mentioned in the comments, how do you want the columns to be named esp for the ones with `.`

Comment: I just changed them to `attributes.Match_addr` and `attributes.StreetName` to match the output form the do.call.